# Programación TS

Tags: typescript, crud

```js
createUsuario(){
  
    this.submitted = true;
    this.mailValid = this.tovpilUtils.isEmailValido(this.userView.email);

    if(this.userView.email && this.mailValid){

      this.apiService.updateUser(this.userView).then(
        data => {
          console.log('Usuario actualizado:', data);
          if(data.status === "ERROR"){
            this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary: 'Actualiza Usuario', detail: data.errorMessage, life: 3000});
            return;
          }
          this.optionDialog = false;
          this.userView = {};
          this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Actualiza Usuario', detail: 'Se creo actualizo usuario correctamente', life: 3000});
      });
        

      }else{
        
      console.log('Antes de llamar a createUser2');
      this.apiService.createUser2(this.userView).then(
        data => {
          console.log('Respuesta de createUser2:', data);

          this.optionDialog = false;
          this.userView = {};
          this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Crear Usuario', detail: 'Se creo usuario correctamente', life: 3000});
      });
      console.log('Después de llamar a createUser2');
      }
      this.loadUsuario();

  }
```

¿No me esta creando un usuario al ejecutar el programa me envía update, y este es mi código?

Estoy tratando de hacer un crud para el modelo de Usuario y mi código solo me esta permitiendo Actualizar y no crear.
Listo ya lo solucione.

Comment: Si no redacte bien si es los mismo. Confirmo lo que no podía hacer era crear y actualizar si.   Saludos y gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: recuerda que el título debe de parecerse a como lo buscarías en internet

Comment: ok gracias pues la verdad es la primera ves que uso stackoverflow pero ahora ya se como usarlo correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no me explique bien en mi pregunta del código, pero analizando mi problema ya logre resolver mi problema.

Solo tenia que manipular el create con el estatus entonces filter el Satatus y lo implemente en el Create.

```
this.userView.status = "A";
```